# Sort dataframe by value in a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this dataframe:

```
     name  age                           scores
0   Alice    8                 (False, 0, 89.1)
1     Bob    7               (True, 136, 79.05)
2   Chuck    9                (True, 138, 75.0)
3   Daren   12               (True, 146, 77.25)
3   Elisa   13               (True, 146, 77.25)
```

Now, I want to filter the dataframe to include only those entries with *True* in the first position of the 'scores' tuple, to obtain this dataframe :

```
     name  age                           scores
1     Bob    7               (True, 136, 79.05)
2   Chuck    9                (True, 138, 75.0)
3   Daren   12               (True, 146, 77.25)
3   Elisa   13               (True, 146, 77.25)
```

I have tried both of these:

```
df = df[df.scores[0] == True]
```

and

```
df = df.drop(df[df.scores[0] == False].index)
```

But I keep getting errors. Does anyone know of an efficient way to filter by value in a tuple? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. You're right! Will fix now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html):

```
df.loc[df.scores.str[0]==True]
```

Answer (score 2):

A reason of the error is because df.score is `Series` but you are trying to use it such as a `list` or `tuple` (e.g., scores[0], scores[1] ...).

[Edited] For this question, @Space Impact 's answer is better (faster and easier).

Instead, you can use `lambda` here, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'Daren', 'Elisa'],
    'age': [8, 7, 9, 12, 13],
    'scores': [(False, 0, 89.1), (True, 136, 79.05), (True, 138, 75.0), (True, 146, 77.25), (True, 146, 77.25)],
})

print(df)
#    name  age              scores
#0  Alice    8    (False, 0, 89.1)
#1    Bob    7  (True, 136, 79.05)
#2  Chuck    9   (True, 138, 75.0)
#3  Daren   12  (True, 146, 77.25)
#4  Elisa   13  (True, 146, 77.25)

df2 = df[df['scores'].apply(lambda x: x[0])]

print(df2)
#    name  age              scores
#1    Bob    7  (True, 136, 79.05)
#2  Chuck    9   (True, 138, 75.0)
#3  Daren   12  (True, 146, 77.25)
#4  Elisa   13  (True, 146, 77.25)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @You_Donut Happy to hear,  Please accept my answer if you think my answer is satisfying, so that other people can see how to solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you will do. One more question, how could I transform this to instead filter rows with x[1] > 140, for example. How do I apply it to the lambda in this case?

Comment: @You_Donut Then, you can simply change the lambda to `lambda x: x[1]>140`

Comment: I am silly, I tried this but was printing something else, so I thought it wasn't working. Thank you for your help!